# Priority queue and heap

Tags: data-structures, go

I'm trying to implement a priority queue based on the example provided in the documentation.
Docs: [priorityQueue](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example)

In short it looks like this (not everything is included):

```
    package pq

    type Item struct {
        container interface{}
        priority  int
        index     int
    }

    type PriorityQueue []*Item

    func NewItem(value interface{}, prio int) *Item {
        return &Item {container: value, priority: prio}
    }

func (pq PriorityQueue) Len() int {
    return len(pq)
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return pq[i].priority > pq[j].priority
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Swap(i, j int) {
    (*pq)[i], (*pq)[j] = (*pq)[j], (*pq)[i]
    (*pq)[i].index = i
    (*pq)[j].index = j
}

    func (pq PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
        fmt.Printf("adr: %p\n", &pq)
        n := len(pq)
        item := x.(*Item)
        item.index = n
        pq = append(pq, item)
    }

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{} {
    old := *pq
    n := len(old)
    itm := old[n - 1]
    itm.index = -1
    *pq = old[0 : n-1]
    return itm.container
}
```

The `main.go` file:

```
func main() {
    q := pq.PriorityQueue{}
    heap.Init(q)
    fmt.Printf("\nAdr: %p\n", &q)
    q.Push(pq.NewItem("h", 2))

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        item := pq.NewItem("test", i * 13 % 7)
        heap.Push(q, item)
    }

    for q.Len() > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Item: " + heap.Pop(q).(string))
    }
}
```

As you can see when comparing to the example I do not use pointers since doing that will give me a compile error telling me that my priority queue does not implement the interface properly.

This leaves me with the following problem when I do:

```
heap.Push(q, item)
```

that the item is not appended to the queue.

I've tried to write out the queues pointer address and it shows different addresses. This explains why it does not work, but souldn't slices not be reference types a long with maps?

And more specificly: How do i solve my problem?

Hope you can help!

Edit: Added full code and error: cannot use q (type pq.PriorityQueue) as type heap.Interface in function argument:
    pq.PriorityQueue does not implement heap.Interface (Pop method has pointer receiver)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Go - Using a container/heap to implement a priority queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704144/go-using-a-container-heap-to-implement-a-priority-queue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the example code shows, the `Push` method must have a pointer receiver.

The trick is that all the calls to `heap.XXX` functions, require that you pass your heap in as a pointer (e.g.: `heap.Init(&pq)`). This is not the case in the code you posted. Here is a working version of your code. You can run it on the [Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/n09e4dwMSL).

Note that in this code, I explicitly initialize the queue as a pointer: `q := new(PriorityQueue)`. And this is what I pass in to all the `heap` functions.

The confusion here arises mostly because you are essentially implementing 2 interfaces.
The `heap.Interface` and the `sort.Interface` (The latter is part of the prior's type definition). But the sort interface is fine with non-pointer receivers, while the other one is not.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "container/heap"

func main() {
    q := new(PriorityQueue)

    heap.Init(q)

    fmt.Printf("\nAdr: %p\n", &q)
    q.Push(NewItem("h", 2))

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        heap.Push(q, NewItem("test", i*13%7))
    }

    for q.Len() > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Item: " + heap.Pop(q).(string))
    }
}

type Item struct {
    container interface{}
    priority  int
    index     int
}

type PriorityQueue []*Item

func NewItem(value interface{}, prio int) *Item {
    return &Item{container: value, priority: prio}
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Len() int {
    return len(pq)
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return pq[i].priority > pq[j].priority
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Swap(i, j int) {
    pq[i], pq[j] = pq[j], pq[i]
    pq[i].index = i
    pq[j].index = j
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("adr: %p\n", pq)
    n := len(*pq)
    item := x.(*Item)
    item.index = n
    *pq = append(*pq, item)
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{} {
    old := *pq
    n := len(old)
    itm := old[n-1]
    itm.index = -1
    *pq = old[0 : n-1]
    return itm.container
}
```

Comment: I tryed doing that, but I might have done something wrong. I get the following error when both uses *PriorityQueue.
src\Algorithms.go:11: cannot use q (type pq.PriorityQueue) as type heap.Interface in function argument:
 pq.PriorityQueue does not implement heap.Interface (Pop method has pointer receiver)

`func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{})`
`func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{}`

Comment: Strange, This should be working just fine. Can you post a little more of your code in your original question?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a solution to your problem. The reasoning behind this goes rather deep. Specifically, in how Go determines if a type implements a given interface. This is something you should read the spec for.